# FB.XdComm is undefined javascript facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Here's the code which I am using to show the compose dialog box from facebook

```
  
var iframeDom=FB.XdComm.Server.singleton.createNamedHiddenIFrame('dialogContent','','fb_permission_iframe',null);
var myDialog=new FB.UI.PopupDialog('Title',iframeDom,true,false).show();
var userId = "user_id";
iframeDom.src=FBIntern.Utility.getFacebookUrl('www')+'inbox/'+'?compose&id='+userId+'&v='+FB.Facebook.version;//or any link that has ur dialog content..
myDialog.show();
```

I have also called FB.Init as well before calling the above code. I am getting FB.XdComm as undefined

I have also referenced http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js under by body tag inside script tag.

Can anyone tell me what's missing

Answer (score 1):

The code seems outdated, these things are no longer part of the Facebook API. You probably want to use the [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui) method.

Comment: can you provide some more information about it. It looks like FB.ui is what I am looking for, but actually I need to show the compose dialog box

Comment: @Sandhurst: have you tried to actually browse and read the link he provided? the example is right there!

Comment: @Sandhurst: You can see a list of available dialogs at the bottom of the [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#methods) page. Compose mail is not there, you probably can't access that this way.